# Google cloud storage access logs are missing object retrieval requests

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm using the google cloud storage for storing items, and set up the access logs for my bucket according to https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/accesslogs

In my bucket access logs I see all the insertions (with method "PUT" in the log records), however none of the retrieval requests that I make.

What should I configure in order to get the logs for object retrievals (method "GET")?

Comment: Are you using the XML or JSON API for the GET requests?

Comment: I'm using the gsutil tool for the get requests: gsutil.py -m cp -R gs://mybucket/results/2014-08-30/ results/
Thinking about it now, could it be that the gsutil "cp" command doesn't map to GET requests? If so, how would I log these requests?